# There are $12$ members in a committee who sit around a table. There is one place specially designated for the chairman.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $12$ members in a committee who sit around a table. There is one place specially designated for the chairman. Besides the chairman, there are $3$ people who constitute a subcommittee. Find the number of seating arrangements if the subcommittee sit together as a block

I gave plenty of thought on this problem but still no progress.
What I am thinking of about the solution is fix the chairman and then choose the subcommittee $\left({11\choose3} \text{ways}\right)$ then arrange the remaining $8$ members.

I am really stuck onto this one, please help!

Comment: Do you get another arrangement if you only change how the members of the subcommittee sits?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think we need to care about selecting the $3$ members of the subcommittee. That is something already done for us. We care only about seating them.

Here's how we can solve the given problem.

After we place the chairman on the seat designated for him, we have $11$ seats and $11$ members remaining. But the $3$ members of the subcommittee must sit together. So let's consider them as one inseparable group/entity/member.

So, we have $8$ members (not part of the subcommittee) and $1$ member representing the subcommittee. These can be arranged in $9!$ ways.

Also, while the members of the subcommittee must sit together, their order is not fixed. So they can be arranged among themselves in $3!$ ways.

That makes the total number of ways to seat all the members of the committee under the given conditions $9! \times 3!$.

---

**Select the subcommittee and seat the members**

If we make the assumption that it is upon us to select the subcommittee, there are ${^{11}C_3}$ ways to do that.

So, altogether there would be ${^{11}C_3} \times 9! \times 3!$ ways. It simplifies to $9 \times 11!$ ways.$^{[1]}$

**Alternative Approach -** We can arrive at the same result from a different direction.

The $11$ members can be seated in $11!$ ways (without any restrictions).

Then for every seating arrangement, we can form a subcommittee in $11 - 3 + 1 = 9$ ways. [Remember, only the people sitting together can for the subcommittee.]

Again, multiplying the to together our answer would be $9 \times 11!$.

---

$^{[1]}$ If the chairman is also to be selected by us, we will need to further multiply by $12$, making the result $9 \times 12!$

Comment: There are $8$ members not in subcommittee and 1 representing them, so $9!$ ways to arrange. And the rest is correct. Total ways = $9! \times 3!$. But still I am confused on how we are able to form all possible subcommittees

Comment: @user1150809 Thanks for pointing that out, I thought there were $7$ members left. Made the correction.

Comment: I need to think more on this

Comment: I think that @user1150809 makes a valid point.  The posted question is open to interpretation.  Your answer quite reasonably assumes that the subcommittee has already been formed.  Absent such an assumption, the specification that the subcommittee must sit together becomes pointless, so your assumption was probably intended by the problem composer.  Anyway, absent this assumption, you can then reason that since any three people might be used to form the subcommittee, any of the $~(11)!~$ ways of seating the remaining 11 people are satisfactory.

Comment: Okay so this problem assumes that there is only $1$ person that is chairman and fix $3$ person that are in subcommittee after that arrange the rest. I was thinking that We need to select one chairman out of twelve then three out of eleven and then they have to sit just next to the chairman whether on right or left.

Comment: I was thinking right, as @user2661923 mentioned.

Comment: @user2661923 "Anyway, absent this assumption, you can then reason that since any three people might be used to form the subcommittee, any of the  (11)!  ways of seating the remaining 11 people are satisfactory." Interesting observation. Inspired me into editing the answer. $11!$ ways would all be satisfactory but they would not cover all the cases, which would be $9 \times 11!$.

Comment: @user1150809 If we need to select both the chairman and the subcommittee, the answer would be $9 \times 12!$. I have edited the answer to include this.

Comment: Wow, Thanks! @Haris

Comment: @user1150809 + to Haris: "...they would not cover all the cases..." : I disagree, because situations where the subcommittee is different but the seating arrangement (relative to the chairman) is identical do not (in my subjective opinion) constitute distinct cases.  This is because of the 1st paragraph of the posted question: "...Find the number of seating arrangements...".  So, you can't have more than $~(11)!~$ *cases*, because that is the maximum number of possible seating arrangements.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes true, I didn’t saw that one. The maximum cases possible is $12!$ if we choose Chairman too because with the same arrangement the rotation will mean different.

Answer (score 2):

There are $12$ choices for the chairman's seat. In the remaining $11$ seats, we can sit the subcomittee in seats $i,i+1,i+2$ for $i=1,...,9$ giving $9$ choices times $3!$ for the arrangement of the subcomittee among themselves. Finally, the remaining $8$ people have to sit in the remaining seats, and can be permuted, so $8!$ ways. In total, $12\cdot 9\cdot 3!\cdot 8!=26,127,360$ ways.

If it is interpreted that the chairman's seat is already allocated, then we don't need the $12$, and it becomes $9\cdot 3!\cdot 8!=2,177,280$ ways. This agrees with Haris' solution.

Comment: You are also assuming that the subcommittee of 3 people has already been formed.  See my comment, following the answer of Haris.

Comment: Please tell me one thing, let $a_1$ be the Chairman and $\{a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ be the subcommittee and arrange all other in one way only. Now if I rotate clockwise by one person then would the arrangement still be the same or different because now $a_{12}$ is Chairman and $\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ are part of subcommittee

Comment: My answer counts rotations as different arrangements.